# Basemap template in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap

Is anyone aware of a method I could follow to create a QGIS basemap template that predefines styles for x number of vector layers. Ideally, the template GUI accepts any vector data of the correct type, the users points to categories, and the template applies particular styles based on the categories identified by the users.

For example, the template may accept roads and be programmed with styles per functional class, and the user points to a road layer as well as the categories of functional class. Endpoint would be a styles basemap without copying styles between maps, also known as streamline basemap setup.

Comment: Performing a certain number of processes on a certain number of objects usually uses a programming language. Do you use PyQGIS?

Comment: Why not save default style (in database or as QML) it may be a simpler way. this question look a that : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339750/auto-styling-qgis-vector-layers-symbology

Comment: Happy to wrangle some snakes

Comment: We make a lot of basemaps where I work, and it would be great to have a template that less GIS savvy co-workers can plug in data, point to the fields and, bam! a basemap appears created. No more relaying basemaps to copy/paste from. Might be a pipe dream.