# Changing range using Apply Symbology From Layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I have a symbology layer saved with 6 ranges and custom colors and the max range is 5.00 - 5.80. I have another shapefile containing the same variable, but the max value is 4.57. So, I used *Apply Symbology by Layer* with  U*pdate Ranges*, but the last range class (5.00 - 5.80) still shows up, how do I make it so that it only shows classes based on the data existing in the shapefile?

Comment: If you click on it in the Layers Styling Panel to select the last range and hit the minus button does that work?  If you need to change a range class click on the Value and change it.  If that works (check your results) then match the legend to it in the same way.

Comment: @johns is there a way to do this in the model builder, I want to automate this process. So, I basically have standard 8 ranges and colors, but I only want ranges to appear based on the data. So, if the variable max values goes into the 6th range class, the 7th and 8th should automatically be removed

Comment: There are quite a few smart contributor here who probably can generate some code to do what you want, but I'm not one of them.  Same for model builder although I could imagine using it to create values for a symbology field which match your desired ranges.  I came across this thread which might give you some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339750/auto-styling-qgis-vector-layers-symbology