# Can I plot the individual style symbols/lines from a single layer to a PDF, and have the PDF have those different styles as different layers

Tags: qgis-3, layers, pdf, batch, plot

I am working with a single layer. I assign the different features different attributes. Then I use categorized styling according to those attributes. In the layer window, these are easy to toggle on or off.
Is there any way to plot the style categories as individual layers in a PDF?
Using the geospatial PDF option in the plot-dialouge only makes the currently turned on symbols (in map-view) to be active.

A solution is to draw the different features in different layers to begin with. But that is inconvenient for other reasons.
Is there any good python script to handle this? Perhaps as a temporary split into different layers according to attribute values, and then plot 1 pdf per attribute-value.

Comment: What software are you using? Please add a tag.

Comment: QGis. Added flag

Comment: You could duplicate the layer and display only on category per duplicated layer.

Comment: That would be the easiest solution. But lets say you have about 20 or more categories. That would take about 30 seconds per duplication including re-styling. Thats 10 minutes! And each time you would add or remove unique values in your attribute table you would need to redo parts of the process

Comment: The plot 1 pdf per attribute value phrase suggests you are making a pdf for each attribute value and then perhaps combining those maps into one pdf.  If so then look at map atlas and have it make a map for each value.  If instead you want a single pdf map with the ability to turn any features with different  values on or off, then you need layers..  You could use the split vector layer tool to create a layer for each value and then perhaps get some help in symbolizing each automatically like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339750/auto-styling-qgis-vector-layers-symbology